# Understand 'case' keyword in partial functions

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

I am new to Scala and I am trying to decode its constructs, I learned about [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) and the syntax is similar to Java switch statement

```
val x: Int = Random.nextInt(10)

x match {
  case 0 => "zero"
  case 1 => "one"
  case 2 => "two"
  case _ => "other"
}
```

This code here is pretty obvious and readable. I came across [partial functions](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples) which are pretty obvious and clear what are they

> A partial function is a function that does not provide an answer for
>   every possible input value it can be given.

What I am confused about is using `case` in the body of a partial function 
like this:

```
val divide2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 42 / d // WHAT IS THIS ?! 
}
```

I don't understand how `case` is used without `match` statement, how does this is interpreted by Scala, how it is read, is it a method, a class or another construct ?, what other ways I can use `case` without `match` statement

Edit:

I tried to play around with this case and still don't get it. For example

```
val SomeFun: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 1000 / d
    case f: Int if f != 2 => 100 / f
    case m: Int if m != 1 => 10 / m
  }
```

How does this work?

Trying this gives an error

```
val SomeFun = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 1000 / d
    case f: Int if f != 2 => 100 / f
    case m: Int if m != 1 => 10 / m
  }


Error:(29, 17) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
```

Is case without match used anywhere else outside a partial function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to answer this question:

> I don't understand how case is used without match statement, how does
>   this is interpreted by Scala, how it is read, is it a method, a class
>   or another construct ?

mainly by referring to [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book-diffs-val-def-scala-functions) article which I will be quoting and paraphrasing.

The reason this works:

```
val f: (Any) => String = {
    case i: Int => "Int"
    case d: Double => "Double"
    case _ => "Other"
}
```

is that the compiler interprets it as an anonymous function.

when you create *val* function, all you’re really doing with code like this is assigning a variable name to an anonymous function.

To support that first statement, Section 15.7 of Programming in Scala states:

> A sequence of cases in curly braces can be used anywhere a function literal can be used.

So it is not really different than using the same syntax inside inside `filter` or `collect`.

The code in the above essentially creates a `Function1` object. As [this source](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) explains:

> The main distinction between PartialFunction and scala.Function1 is
>   that the user of a PartialFunction may choose to do something
>   different with input that is declared to be outside its domain.

Answer (score 6):

It means that a partial function will be applied only if the input param can match case expression.

The actual class generated is something like this:

```
val divide = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
    def apply(x: Int) = 42 / x
    def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x != 0
}
```

Using orElse you can apply or handle multiple definitions:

```
funcForInt orElse funcForDouble orElse funcForString
```

Nice composition?

Edit:

```
val SomeFun: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 1000 / d
    case f: Int if f != 2 => 100 / f
    case m: Int if m != 1 => 10 / m
  }
```

The above is using anonymous class feature. If you remove the variable's type, you are just giving it a block expression with some case expressions which compiler can't really use.

Ref: https://www.james-willett.com/scala-anonymous-classes

Comment: I understand how it works but I don't understand the grammar for applying or using case

Comment: and how does this case translate to use apply, is defined, and so on ...

Answer (score 5):

It is a pattern-matching anonymous function as described in [the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions).

> Trying this gives an error
>
> ```
> val SomeFun = ...
> ```

This is because parameter type needs to be known, just like for "normal" anonymous functions `x => ...`. The difference is that in a pattern-matching anonymous function there's no place to specify the parameter type directly (equivalent to `(x: Int) => ...`), so there *must* be an expected type e.g. `val SomeFun: PartialFunction[Int, Int]` or `val SomeFun: Int => Int` .

```
val SomeFun: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 1000 / d
    case f: Int if f != 2 => 100 / f
    case m: Int if m != 1 => 10 / m
  }
```

gets translated to

```
val SomeFun: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
  override def apply(x: Int) = x match {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 1000 / d
    case f: Int if f != 2 => 100 / f
    case m: Int if m != 1 => 10 / m
  }
  override def isDefined(x: Int) = x match {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => true
    case f: Int if f != 2 => true
    case m: Int if m != 1 => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```